Custom MLPPolicy issues in Ray RLLIB
I'm trying to create a custom MLP-based policy in Ray Rllib using this code below:
python: 3.10
Rayrlib version: 2.23
class CustomMLPModel(TorchModelV2, nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, obs_space, action_space, num_outputs, model_config, name):
        TorchModelV2.__init__(self, obs_space, action_space, num_outputs, model_config, name)
        nn.Module.__init__(self)

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(obs_space.shape[0], 128)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, 128)
        self.actor = nn.Linear(128, num_outputs)
        self.critic = nn.Linear(128, 1)

    @override(ModelV2)
    def forward(self, input_dict, state, seq_lens):
        x = torch.relu(self.fc1(input_dict["obs"]))
        x = torch.relu(self.fc2(x))
        logits = self.actor(x)
        self._value_out = self.critic(x)
        return logits, state

    @override(ModelV2)
    def value_function(self):
        return self._value_out

ModelCatalog.register_custom_model("custom_policy_model", CustomMLPModel)


environment_name = "learning_rate_env"

# # Register the environment with RLlib
register_env("learning_rate_env", lambda config: env_creator(config))

test_dir = f"/content/drive/MyDrive/results/{environment_name}"

config = (
    PPOConfig()
    .rollouts(num_rollout_workers=1, num_envs_per_worker=1, rollout_fragment_length=128)
    .training(
        model={"custom_model": "custom_policy_model"},
        train_batch_size=128,
        lr=1e-4,
        gamma=0.95,
        lambda_=0.9,
        use_gae=True,
        clip_param=0.4,
        grad_clip=None,
        entropy_coeff=0.1,
        vf_loss_coeff=0.5,
        sgd_minibatch_size=32,
        num_sgd_iter=4,
    )    .environment(env="CartPole-v1")
    .framework(framework="torch")
    .resources(num_cpus_per_worker=1, num_gpus_per_worker=1/1)
)


results = tune.Tuner(
    "PPO",
    param_space=config.to_dict(),
    run_config=air.RunConfig(
        name="PPO",
        storage_path=test_dir,
        stop={"timesteps_total": 1000},
        verbose=1,
        checkpoint_config=air.CheckpointConfig(
            checkpoint_frequency=5,
            checkpoint_at_end=True,
        ),
    ),
).fit()

But I got the following error
(PPO pid=7048) AssertionError
(PPO pid=7048) Traceback (most recent call last):
(PPO pid=7048)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ray/rllib/env/env_runner_group.py", line 169, in __init__
(PPO pid=7048)     self._setup(
(PPO pid=7048)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ray/rllib/env/env_runner_group.py", line 239, in _setup
(PPO pid=7048)     self.add_workers(
(PPO pid=7048)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ray/rllib/env/env_runner_group.py", line 754, in add_workers
(PPO pid=7048)     raise result.get()
(PPO pid=7048)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ray/rllib/utils/actor_manager.py", line 500, in _fetch_result
(PPO pid=7048)     result = ray.get(ready)
(PPO pid=7048)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ray/_private/auto_init_hook.py", line 21, in auto_init_wrapper
(PPO pid=7048)     return fn(*args, **kwargs)
(PPO pid=7048)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ray/_private/client_mode_hook.py", line 103, in wrapper
(PPO pid=7048)     return func(*args, **kwargs)
(PPO pid=7048)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ray/_private/worker.py", line 2613, in get
(PPO pid=7048)     values, debugger_breakpoint = worker.get_objects(object_refs, timeout=timeout)
(PPO pid=7048)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ray/_private/worker.py", line 863, in get_objects
(PPO pid=7048)     raise value
(PPO pid=7048)   File "python/ray/_raylet.pyx", line 2283, in ray._raylet.task_execution_handler
(PPO pid=7048)   File "python/ray/_raylet.pyx", line 2179, in ray._raylet.execute_task_with_cancellation_handler
(PPO pid=7048)   File "python/ray/_raylet.pyx", line 1834, in ray._raylet.execute_task
(PPO pid=7048)   File "python/ray/_raylet.pyx", line 1835, in ray._raylet.execute_task
(PPO pid=7048)   File "python/ray/_raylet.pyx", line 2073, in ray._raylet.execute_task
(PPO pid=7048)   File "python/ray/_raylet.pyx", line 1100, in ray._raylet.store_task_errors
(PPO pid=7048) ray.exceptions.ActorDiedError: The actor died because of an error raised in its creation task, ray::RolloutWorker.__init__() (pid=7110, ip=172.28.0.12, actor_id=7767b90b96e19069a444d84901000000, repr=<ray.rllib.evaluation.rollout_worker.RolloutWorker object at 0x781fc356cd00>)
(PPO pid=7048)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ray/rllib/evaluation/rollout_worker.py", line 532, in __init__
(PPO pid=7048)     self._update_policy_map(policy_dict=self.policy_dict)
(PPO pid=7048)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ray/rllib/evaluation/rollout_worker.py", line 1737, in _update_policy_map
(PPO pid=7048)     self._build_policy_map(
(PPO pid=7048)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ray/rllib/evaluation/rollout_worker.py", line 1848, in _build_policy_map
(PPO pid=7048)     new_policy = create_policy_for_framework(
(PPO pid=7048)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ray/rllib/utils/policy.py", line 141, in create_policy_for_framework
(PPO pid=7048)     return policy_class(observation_space, action_space, merged_config)
(PPO pid=7048)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ray/rllib/algorithms/ppo/ppo_torch_policy.py", line 64, in __init__
(PPO pid=7048)     self._initialize_loss_from_dummy_batch()
(PPO pid=7048)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ray/rllib/policy/policy.py", line 1445, in _initialize_loss_from_dummy_batch
(PPO pid=7048)     postprocessed_batch = self.postprocess_trajectory(self._dummy_batch)
(PPO pid=7048)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ray/rllib/algorithms/ppo/ppo_torch_policy.py", line 215, in postprocess_trajectory
(PPO pid=7048)     return compute_gae_for_sample_batch(
(PPO pid=7048)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ray/rllib/evaluation/postprocessing.py", line 195, in compute_gae_for_sample_batch
(PPO pid=7048)     assert vf_preds.shape == rewards.shape


I have tried to debug it but I couldn't figure out what I am did wrong. Any pointer would go along way. Ideally, I want to use a lstm_based policy but I am starting with a simple mlp first.

It is saying that the rewards' dimension is different from your value's dim provided by your value network. Both of them should be [batch_size]. I previously encountered similar problems as my impl of value_function() of the custom model does a torch squeeze() reducing from [batch_size, value, 1] to [batch_size, value] but when batch_size = 1 squeeze will turn it to a scalar which makes the dim assert to fire. I fixed it by changing it to squeeze(-1) which ensures the dim provided by the value_function() is correct.
